# Store the Head section within Coldfusion, without hard coding in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, coldfusion, xslt-1.0, meta-tags

I am trying to convert this part of my XSLT 1.0 from being hard coded with the meta tags, in case I wanted to change them in the future. Is there a way to display the meta tags that included the stylesheet, keywords and description, instead within the ColdFusion?

I have tried and got it to almost work with the stylesheet, but it only displays it above `<html>` or under `</html>` not inside `<head>`, which is where I need it to go for all of these.

Any advice on how I should display this that way?

**CFM**

**

```
<cfset MyXmlFile = Expandpath("events.xml")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xmlInput"  file="#MyXmlFile#">
<cfset MyXmlFile = Expandpath("events.xsl")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xslInput" file="#MyXmlFile#">
<cfset xslParam = StructNew() >
<cfset xslParam["pram"] = "#url.pram#" >
<cfset xmlOutput = XMLTransform(xmlInput, xslInput, xslParam)>
<!--- data is output --->
<cfcontent type="text/html" reset="true" /><!DOCTYPE html>
<cfoutput>
<cfset style='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">' />
#style#
#xmloutput#
</cfoutput>
```

**

**XSLT**

```
 <xsl:element name="meta"><xsl:attribute name="name">description</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="content">Listings of all events</xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="meta"><xsl:attribute name="name">keywords</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="content">events, event, music, help, information</xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="link"><xsl:attribute name="rel">icon</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="href">images/favicon.ico</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="type">image/x-icon</xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="link"><xsl:attribute name="rel">shortcut icon</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="href">images/favicon.ico</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="type">image/x-icon</xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="link"><xsl:attribute name="rel">stylesheet</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="type">text/css</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="href">stylesheet.css</xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
```

**HTML** Top Part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="description" content="Listings of all events">
      <meta name="keywords" content="events, event, music, help, information">
      <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
      <title>London Comic Con</title>
   </head>
   <body>
```

---

**XML** Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<events 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="events.xsd">

    <venue id="01" vtitle="ExCeL Exhibition Centre" location="London" telephone="0844 448 7600">
    <about>The ExCel Exhibition Centre was opened in November 2000 and was built by Sir Robert MacAlpine. The venue was most recently bought over acquired by the Abu Dhabi National Exhibitions Company in 2008. Phase II was completed on 1 May 2010. This expansion created The International Convention Centre London (ICC London) adding to ExCeL's event space, as well as further meeting space and banqueting facilities.</about>
    <event name="London Comic Con" date="2013-10-12">
        <image>images/MCM1.jpg</image><attribute>London Anime Event</attribute>
        <description>A convention for all things Anime, video games and Japanese culture.</description>
        <keywords>events, event, music, help, information</keywords>
        <ticket_price type="adult" status="none">&#163;18.00</ticket_price>
        <ticket_price type="child" status="available">&#163;8.00</ticket_price>
        <ticket_price type="junior" status="available">&#163;0.00</ticket_price>
        <email>london@mcmexpo.net</email>
    </event>
```

Comment: Are you asking whether the values of the description or keywords can be obtained from the source XML being transformed? If so, the answer is yes but it would be helpful if you posted an example of the XML being transformed. If you want to know whether or not it is possible to reference an external XML config or even a different section of the XSLT, the answer is also yes. Please be a little more specific about where you want to obtain these values from and someone can suggest ways to implement a solution.

Comment: that was an example I want all of this data, to be linked from the XML to then be pulled into the XSLT, I can't see how you would do this for meta tags with the icons and stylesheet

Comment: So, you would want the content from the `<description>` in the `<meta name="description">` and the content from the `<keywords>` in the `<meta name="keywords">`? Are you generating one HTML page per event, or are you creating a page per `<venue>` and would want the content from each of the `<event>`'s `<description>` and `<keywords>` concatenated?

Comment: Yes to description and keywords, this is the same with the other meta tags and the stylesheet. I'm using ColdFusion with parameters to generate the events selected from a listing page but I know how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this way will not work for me. I have changed the question to explain how I am trying to do this, as the other way did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this work by adding creating a `cfhtmlhead` section within the ColdFusion file. Per [the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_g-h_08.html):

> Use this tag for embedding JavaScript code, or putting other HTML
>   tags, such as meta, link, title, or base in an HTML page header.

**CFM - Example**

```
<cfhtmlhead text='<link rel="stylesheet" 
     type="text/css" 
     href="stylesheet.css">#chr(13)##chr(10)#'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define a template to match the elements that you want to produce `<meta>` elements for and construct the corresponding `<meta>` elements with their atttributes.

This example uses an element literal with attribute value templates:

```
<xsl:template match="description | keywords" mode="meta">
  <meta name="{local-name()}" content="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Applied in a stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <xsl:call-template name="head"/>
    <!--body stuff goes here-->
  </html> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="head">
  <head>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/events/venue/event/*" mode="meta"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
</xsl:template>

<!--template to match the elements that you want to produce meta elements for-->
<xsl:template match="description | keywords" mode="meta">
  <meta name="{local-name()}" content="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--for all other elements in this mode, do nothing -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="meta"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this way will not work for me. I have changed the question to explain how I am trying to do this, as the other way did not work